# how to add order grid serializer in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, order-grid, grid-serlization

i want to create the `Order Grid Serializer` functionality.

If Anyone create that type functionality then please guide me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i figure out myself. hope it will help Community.

First add the `tab` for assign Order

```
$this->addTab('order_section', array(
         'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Assign Order'),
         'title'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Assign Order'),
         'url'       => $this->getUrl('*/*/assignorder', array('_current' => true)),
         'class'     => 'ajax',
      ));
```

Then order grid

```
<?php 

class SIE_Assignorder_Adminhtml_Assignorder_Edit_Tab_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid

{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('entity_id');
       $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');

    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);  //Dont save paramters in session or else it creates problems
    $this->setUseAjax(true);


}
protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();


        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();

    }

protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
     //   Set custom filter for in order flag
        if ($column->getId() == 'order_id') { 
            $sId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $ordermodel = Mage::getModel('assignorder/checklist')->getchecklistorder($sId);
        $orderIds = "";
                 if(count($ordermodel)) {

              $orders = explode(',',$ordermodel['order_id']);
             }


            if (empty($orderIds)) { 
                $orderIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue() and $orderIds != 0) {  

                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$orderIds));

            } 
            else { 
                if($orderIds) { 

                    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin'=>$orderIds));
                }
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
   {
   $this->addColumn('order_id', array(
            'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
            'type'  => 'checkbox',
            'name'  => 'order',
            'values'=> $this->_getSelectedOrders(),
            'align' => 'center',
            'index' => 'entity_id'
        ));
    $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Order #'),
            'align' => 'left',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));
     $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Grand Total'),
            'align' => 'left',
            'index' => 'grand_total',
        ));


  }

 public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getData('grid_url') ? $this->_getData('grid_url') : $this->getUrl('*/*/assignordergrid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
public function _getSelectedOrders() {

             $orders = array_keys($this->getSelectedOrders());

        return $orders;
    }

    public function getSelectedOrders() {
        $orders = array();

         $sId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if (isset($sId)) {
            $customers=array();
           $ordermodel = Mage::getModel('assignorder/checklist')->getchecklistorder($sId);

            if(count($ordermodel))
            {
              $orders = explode(',',$ordermodel['order_id']);
              $a=0;
             }
          }

        return $orders;
    }




}
```

xml code

```
 <adminhtml_assignorder_checklist_assignorder>
       <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
           <block type="assignorder/adminhtml_checklist_edit_tab_grid" name="ordersgrid"/>
           <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="grid_serializer">
               <reference name="grid_serializer">
                   <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                       <grid_block_name>ordersgrid</grid_block_name>
                       <data_callback>_getSelectedOrders</data_callback>
                       <hidden_input_name>links[orders]</hidden_input_name>
                       <reload_param_name>orders</reload_param_name>
                   </action>

               </reference>
           </block>
       </block>
   </adminhtml_assignorder_checklist_assignorder>
   <adminhtml_assignorder_checklist_assignordergrid>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
            <block type="assignorder/adminhtml_checklist_edit_tab_grid" name="ordersgrid"/>
        </block>
   </adminhtml_assignorder_checklist_assignordergrid>
```

for controller

```
public function assignorderAction(){


    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('ordersgrid')->setOrders($this->getRequest()->getPost('orders', null))
    ;
    $this->renderLayout();
}
public function assignordergridAction(){
    $sId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $ordermodel = Mage::getModel('assignorder/checklist')->getchecklistorder($sId);
     $orders ="";
     if(count($ordermodel))
     {
    $orders = explode(',',$ordermodel['order_id']);
      }
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('ordersgrid')
    ->setOrders($this->getRequest()->getPost('orders', $order));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

getting the values  of grid

```
if(isset($postData['links'])){
                  $orders = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($postData['links']['orders']); //Save the array to your database

                $orders = implode(",", $orders);


            }
```