# how to Store Values In Database for Custom Grid Serializer (Customer)?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection, grid-serlization, customer-grid

I am Created Custom Module for Customer Grid Serializer and now I want to Store That Values in Diffrent Table.
Can Any one Help me? Any Kind of help will appreiciated.

My Grid Code : `app/code/local/Sigmasolve/Recipe/Block/Adminhtml/Recipe/Edit/Tab`

```
     <?php

class Sigmasolve_Recipe_Block_Adminhtml_Recipe_Edit_Tab_Customers extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
   public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setId('recipe_customers');
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect();

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('selected_customers', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Popular'),
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'field_name'=> 'selected_customers',
            'values'    => $this->getSelectedCustomers(),
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name',
            'align'     => 'left',
        ));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/customersGrid', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```

Comment: share your gird code.

Comment: I put my code in Question

Comment: you code in custroller save action to store value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will your custom grid field name `orders` change it accordingly your **name**

```
 $this->addColumn('selected_customers', array(
        'header'    => $this->__('Popular'),
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
        'align'     => 'center',
        'name'     => 'customers',
        'field_name'=> 'selected_customers',
        'values'    => $this->getSelectedCustomers(),
    ));


if(isset($postData['links'])){
      $customgrid = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($postData['links']['customers']); //Save the array to your database
      $customgridvalues = implode(",", $customgrid);
      }
```

complete [example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98353/how-to-add-order-grid-serializer-in-custom-module?rq=1) of grid

Comment: can I ask for that in which table data are store in databse?

Comment: I want to create new table for that?

Comment: you want to store these values in different table  `$customgridvalues`. these are your values.